# How can I prevent the logging of all keywords except Log keyword in robot framework?

Tags: logging, robotframework

I am a beginner in robot framework. I want the log file of my robot test to contain the logs for only the log keyword. I tried to use removekeyword all. But It removed all keywords.
[image]

When I dont use the removekeyword, My log becomes messy
[image]

How can I log only the keyword-Log to my file? Also, How can I log the value of ${resp.status_code} in the log, instead of it being showed as a text in the above screenshot? Log to console is printing the value in console, but when I use Log, I am seeing it as the variable itself.

Edit:
What I want is

```
Keyword When I post a post Request
           -keyword Log value of{resp_status code}
           -keyword Log ****************************
Keyword THEN verify status code is 200
           -keyword Log status code is 200
```

I don't want any other logs to show up other than the log keyword

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want it too look like. Also it helps if you let us know what you've tried (I see the remove keywords argument used in the first image) and why it doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: I have added the edits in the original question